# Display Networkx 2.2 MultiGraphs using graphviz or pydot

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, graphviz, pygraphviz, pydot

I am using `python3.4`, `networkx2.2`, `graphviz2.38` and `pygraphviz1.3` for creating and showing graphs in python. I have the following piece of code that correctly writes the multigraph to a `png` file.

```
import networkx as nx
import pylab as plt
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout, to_agraph
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import write_dot, to_pydot

ic_G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
ic_G.add_nodes_from(['A', 'B', 'C'])
nx.add_path(ic_G, ['A', 'B', 'C'])
#ic_G.add_edge('A','B')

dot_G = to_pydot(ic_G)
print(dot_G)


A = to_agraph(ic_G)
A.layout('dot')
A.draw('abc.png')
```

The console shows the multigraph in correct format as shown below

```
digraph  {
B;
A;
C;
B -> C  [key=0];
A -> B  [key=0];
}
```

and the following file is written in the same directory:

[image: multidigraph]

The problem arises when I add duplicate edges in the multigraph i.e when I un-comment the following line from the code above

```
#ic_G.add_edge('A','B')
```

I get the following exception on the console

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Basit\Anaconda3\envs\python34\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py",
>   line 478, in add_edge
>       eh = gv.agedge(self.handle, uh, vh, key, _Action.create) KeyError: 'agedge: no key'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:/GitHub/misc/BP_Graphs/test2.py", line 16, in 
>       A = to_agraph(ic_G)   File "C:\Users\Basit\Anaconda3\envs\python34\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_agraph.py",
>   line 161, in to_agraph
>       A.add_edge(u, v, key=str(key))   File "C:\Users\Basit\Anaconda3\envs\python34\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py",
>   line 481, in add_edge
>       eh = gv.agedge(self.handle, uh, vh, key, _Action.find) KeyError: 'agedge: no key'

The `to_pydot` function works fine and console prints the multiple edges of multigraph in dot format as shown below

```
digraph  {
B;
C;
A;
B -> C  [key=0];
A -> B  [key=0];
A -> B  [key=1];
}
```

My question is, why `to_agraph` is failing for multiple edges in a multigraph? Is there a way to convert the output of `to_pydot` function into a `png` file without having to use `to_agraph`?

Comment: `Dot` object can be written to `png` file using `write_png` function. So only question that remains is why `to_agraph` is throwing exception in case of multiple edges?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with either python 2.7 or python 3.5; both produce the multi-graph version ok.  This github issue looks rather similar: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/2012 and a main developer indicates the problem is within (py)graphviz.

Comment: what version of `networkx` and `pygraphviz` you are using? I also suspect it to be `pygraphviz` or `graphviz` issue. I was able to render the `Multigraph` with `pydot` just fine.

Comment: in py2, pygraphviz is 1.3.1, networkx is 2.1. in py3, pygraphviz is 1.5, networkx=2.2.